# Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I wrote the code, but I get the following message in pycharm(2019.1):
"Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks"

```py
    def data_is_valid(data):
        keys_and_types = {
            'comment': (str, type(None)),
            'from_budget': (bool, type(None)),
            'to_member': (int, type(None)),
            'survey_request': (int, type(None)),
        }

        def type_is_valid(test_key, test_value):
            return isinstance(test_value, keys_and_types[test_key])

        type_is_valid('comment', 3)
```

I really do not understand this message well. Did I do something wrong or is it a bug in pycharm?
The error disappears if I explicitly typecast to tuple.

```py
def type_is_valid(test_key, test_value):
    return isinstance(test_value, tuple(keys_and_types[test_key]))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you tell me what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what this warning means and how it relates to my code. And if this is an error in pycharm linter, I want to see an example in which this warning will be valid.

Comment: This is an added type hinting error, but the code will run if you ignore that error, also you can just do `'comment': str` ..etc Pycharm supports type hinting checks: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html

Comment: btw, you're not type casting to tuple, casting doesn't exist in python. you're taking the tuple as an iterable and telling the tuple constructor to build you a tuple from it. Which doesn't change anything as far as python's code is concerned, but then pycharm doesn't trip over the square brackets any more and knows it's not something out of the `typing` module.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That looks like a bug in pycharm where it's a bit overeager in assuming that you're using the `typing` module in an unintended way. See this example here where that assumption would have been correct:

[image]

The classes in the `typing` module are only useful in a type annotation context, not to inspect or compare to actual classes, which is what `isinstance` tries to do. Since pycharm sees a simple object with square brackets that do not contain a literal, it jumps to the wrong conclusion you are seeing.

Your code is fine, you can use it exactly as it is.

Comment: Also note that if you are annoyed by that, you can use `keys_and_types.get(test_key)` as well, though as @Arne said, what you have is perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and helpful answer. Now I understand what this error is about.

Comment: @Mogost happy to help =) Also good on you for filing the issue with pycharm already so that this can get fixed asap.

Comment: I don't understand this answer - it literally says "classes in the typing module are only useful in a type annotation context, not to inspect or compare to actual classes, which is what isinstance tries to do". That's exactly why PyCharm gives the warning, you cannot call `isinstance()` with `List[int]` as the type, as generics cannot be used with Instance and class checks. How is this a problem with PyCharm? In other words, running `isinstance([1], List[int])` after `from typing import List`, will result in an error in Python, no PyCharm involved.

Comment: Yeah, I'm demonstrating PyCharm's hint the way it was intended. In the case of OP it's a bug, because apparently the rule for PyCharm isn't "give the hint if there is a generic in an isinstance call", it's "give the hint if there are square brackets in an isinstance call", as if generics were the only objects that implement `__get_item__`. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Grismar: `isinstance([1], List[int])` is indeed an error, but that was just an example to demonstrate Pycharm's intentions. OP's `isinstance(somevar, somedict[key])` is **not** an error (provided `somedict` maps to types, which is the case), but Pycharm incorrectly reports it.

Comment: is the use of the classes in typing for instance checks frowned upon? It is totally able to do it.  Just that it doesn't do it for parametrized generics or subscripted generics.  For example
`isinstance([], Sequence) and not isinstance({}, Sequence)` would result in `True`.    A setup that would result in a subscripted generic error would be like `isinstance([1,2,3], Sequence[int])`, and the parametrized generic error would result from something like `isinstance({"hi":"there"}, dict[str,str])`.  Any literature that would frown upon the working cases I showed above?

Comment: @Marc That's relatively new, when typing was first introduced, only a handful of classes had identical _actual_ type as well as typing/generic type. The example in my post with `typing.List` not being the correct type of `[]` still holds, but in recent pythons versions support was added to use actual types like `list` or sane abstract types like `Sequence` directly for type checks instead of the `typing`-types. Your working examples are completely fine and the way it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I will not repeat after others that this is a pycharm bug. Just if you are a perfectionist and the error hurts your eyes, add the comment

`# noqa`

to the line where the "error" is

Answer (score 1):

This was a known bug in PyCharm 2018, reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31788).

There are some related bugs still in more recent PyCharm versions, e.g. PyCharm 2021.2.2, [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32860).

In general, when you found that some PyCharm warning is incorrect, I would first isolate a simple test case where it becomes more clear what PyCharm is actually incorrect about. When it is clear that PyCharm is wrong with the warning, then you should always fill a bug report about it (or maybe search for existing bug reports first). Here this is clear because PyCharm says you cannot do sth, while in fact you can, so sth is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's agreed it's a bug, you can suppress it in Pycharm by the line:

```
# noinspection PyTypeHints
```