# isinstance showing error when lookup is used for type comparison (Possible Pycharm Error)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.9

I am trying to write a function that checks that data read in is of the same type as a dictionary of default values. My code is:

```
defaults: dict[str, type] = {
    "a": str,
    "b": int,
}

read_in = {
    "a": "life_of",
    "b": "brian"
}

for key, value in read_in.items():
    correct_type = defaults[key]
    if not isinstance(value, correct_type):
        print("wrong type")
        break
```

The `correct type` in `isinstance` shows as an error in my IDE (Pycharm community edition) . However, the code does run correctly (at least in this simple instance). From this I can see two options.

1. Pycharm has a bug which causes an error to show where none exits
2. I've made some kind of horrible mistake that will introduce a hard to debug error into my code.

The error is "Parameterized generics cannot be used with instance and class checks"

Does anyone know which it is?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493140/parameterized-generics-cannot-be-used-with-class-or-instance-checks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an existing pycharm issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32860). If you dont like the error you can add `#noqa` to the line:

```
defaults: dict[str, type] = {
    "a": str,
    "b": int,
}

read_in = {
    "a": "life_of",
    "b": "brian"
}

for key, value in read_in.items():
    correct_type = defaults[key]
    if not isinstance(value, correct_type): # noqa
        print("wrong type")
        break
```