# In python multimethod, how to define a case for empty list?

Tags: python, multimethod

For example, I define

```
@multimethod
def f(x:list[str]):
    return 1
@multimethod
def f(x:list[int]):
    return 0
```

then

```
f([])
```

gives error

> DispatchError: ('f: 2 methods found', (<class 'multimethod.<class
> 'list'>'>,), [(<class 'multimethod.list[str]'>,), (<class
> 'multimethod.list[int]'>,)])

how to define a case specific for empty list?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're checking some property of your list you should use `@overload` instead of `@multimethod` that way you can supply some custom predicate. Note as per the [documentation](https://multimethod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#overload) "Overloads dispatch on annotated predicates. Each predicate is checked in the reverse order of registration" so be carefull with the order. Anyways we can define some simple function `isinstance(lst, list) and not lst` and use lambda notation to write:

```py
from multimethod import overload
@overload
def f(lst: list[str]):
    return 1
@overload
def f(lst: list[int]):
    return 0
@overload
def f(lst: lambda lst: isinstance(lst, list) and not lst): # the not lst checks that it has elements
    return 2
print(f(["1"])) # returns 1
print(f([1])) # returns 0
print(f([])) # returns 2
```

And it all seems to work as expected. If you have issues with the `isinstance` you can also use `multimethod`'s built in `isa` function like this:

```py
from multimethod import isa, overload
@overload
def f(lst: list[str]):
    return 1
@overload
def f(lst: list[int]):
    return 0
@overload
def f(lst: lambda lst:isa(list)(lst) and not lst): # the not lst checks that it has elements
    return 2
print(f(["1"])) # returns 1
print(f([1])) # returns 0
print(f([])) # returns 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. But your code is not working on my computer. There is "TypeError: isinstance() argument 2 cannot be a parameterized generic" when executing `print(f(["1"]))`

Comment: Wow, that's really strange, do you happen to use Pycharm because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493140/parameterized-generics-cannot-be-used-with-class-or-instance-checks would indicate it could be a Pycharm bug. If that isn't the case I've updated my post to use the multimethod `isa` instead of `isinstance`.